# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to pass form values, check them and then return the response with jquery, everything gets passed correctly, the image gets uploaded and the path gets added to the database, but instead of returning the message on the same page, it redirects to the addmember.php, doesn't even go through the checks - like the javascript file doesn't even exist and it has been bothering me for quite a while... I've tried searching but I didn't find anything relatable to me since the problem lies in the picture/image...

> > > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null

**addmember.js and the **form**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submit").click(function() {

    var membershipnumber = $("#membershipnumber").val();
    var membername = $("#membername").val();
    var membersurname = $("#membersurname").val();
    var memberdate = $("#memberdate").val();
    var memberphonenumber = $("#memberphonenumber").val();
    var memberemail = $("#memberemail").val();
    var memberpicture = document.getElementById("#memberpicture").val();

    if ((membershipnumber == "") || (membername == "") || (membersurname == "") || (memberdate == "") || (memberphonenumber == "")) {
      $("#message").html("<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>Polja označena sa * ne smeju biti prazna.</div>");
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addmember.php",
        data: {
          "membershipnumber": membershipnumber,
          "membername": membername,
          "membersurname": membersurname,
          "memberdate": memberdate,
          "memberphonenumber": memberphonenumber,
          "memberemail": memberemail,
          "memberpicture": memberpicture
        },
        success: function(html) {
          var text = $(html).text();
          var response = text.substr(text.length - 4);

          $("#message").html(html);
        },
        error: function() {

        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          $("#message").html("<p class='text-center'><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'></p>")
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="createnewmember" id="createnewmember" method="post" action="addmember.php" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- name and surname -->
    <label for="membername" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Ime i prezime:<font color="#d9534f">*</font></label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input name="membername" id="membername" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ime" autofocus />
        <input name="membersurname" id="membersurname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Prezime" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /name and surname -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- date of birth -->
    <label for="memberdate" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Datum rođenja:<font color="#d9534f">*</font></label>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input name="memberdate" id="memberdate" type="date" class="form-control" value="1990-01-01" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /date of birth -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- membership number (scanned with barcode scanner) -->
    <label for="membershipnumber" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Članski broj:<font color="#d9534f">*</font></label>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input name="membershipnumber" id="membershipnumber" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Članski broj" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Očitajte bar-kod sa nekorišćene kartice." />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /membmership number -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- phone number -->
    <label for="memberphonenumber" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Broj telefona:<font color="#d9534f">*</font></label>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input name="memberphonenumber" id="memberphonenumber" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Broj telefona" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /phone number -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- email -->
    <label for="memberemail" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email adresa:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input name="memberemail" id="memberemail" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email adresa" />
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input name="memberemailinglist" id="memberemailinglist" type="checkbox" disabled/> Prijavi na mailing listu?</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /email -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- picture -->
    <label for="memberpicture" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Slika:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <label class="btn btn-default" for="memberpicture">
        <input id="memberpicture" name="memberpicture" type="file" style="display:none;" onchange="$('#memberpicture-info').html($(this).val());" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg" class="form-control" />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> Traži...
      </label>
      <span class="label label-danger" id="memberpicture-info">Nije izabrana ni jedna slika...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /picture -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <span class="pull-right">Polja označena sa <font color="#d9534f">*</font> su obavezna! &nbsp</span>
    <!-- required fields text -->
  </div>

  <button name="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Podnesi</button>
  <!-- submit button -->

</form>
<!-- /form -->
```

**addmember.php**

```
<?php
require 'includes/functions.php';
include_once 'config.php';

$membershipnumber = $_POST['membershipnumber'];
$membername = $_POST['membername']." ".$_POST['membersurname'];
$membersurname = $_POST['membersurname'];
$memberdate = $_POST['memberdate'];
$memberphonenumber = $_POST['memberphonenumber'];
$memberemail = $_POST['memberemail'];

$memberpicture_dir = '/images/members';
if(isset($_FILES['memberpicture'])) {
    $memberpicture_temp = $_FILES['memberpicture']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = pathinfo(basename($_FILES['memberpicture']['name']), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $memberpicture = $membershipnumber.".".$ext;
    move_uploaded_file($memberpicture_temp , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/spartangym/images/members/' . $memberpicture);
} else {
    $memberpicture = "nopicture.jpg";
}

$regdate = new DateTime();
$memberregdate = $regdate->getTimestamp();
$memberexpires = $memberregdate + 2592000;

if (strlen($memberemail) > 0 && !filter_var($memberemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == true) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Email adresa nije validna.</div><div id="returnVal" style="display:none;">false</div>';

} else {
    $a = new AddMemberForm;
    $response = $a->createMember($membershipnumber, $membername, $memberdate, $memberphonenumber, $memberemail, $memberpicture, $memberregdate, $memberexpires);

    if ($response == 'true') {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Član '. $membername .' je uspešno dodat u bazu.</div><div id="returnVal" style="display:none;">true</div>';

    } else {
        mySqlErrors($response);

    }
};
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
var memberpicture = document.getElementById("#memberpicture").val();
```

Native methods don't have `val()`, nor should you include the hash.
As `val()` is a jQuery method, you probably wanted to do

```
var memberpicture = $("#memberpicture").val();
```

The native alternative would be

```
var memberpicture = document.getElementById("memberpicture").value;
```

Comment: The image upload gets skipped even though I chose a valid .jpg picture,  http://image.prntscr.com/image/067b3b25cf02417b81858b813b669641.png

Comment: Oh, I see, that tag is an input of type `file`. You **can not** get the image that way, nor send it that way, you need `formData`, and the image is in the `files` property etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, looks like I need to do a little more research.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation looks fine, but on-click you should use event.preventDefault() to keep the form from submitting and only allow the submission in the event of all fields being valid.

Usage here:
https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Adding event.preventDefault(); stops the redirection, but the error is still there and this time it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

at first check

before check

```
 var membershipnumber = $("#membershipnumber").val();
```

after check

```
var membershipnumber='none object';
if(typeof($('#membershipnumber'))!="undefined")
{
   membershipnumber= $('#membershipnumber').val();
}
alert(membershipnumber);
```